# What is this program doing when it responds slowly?

Tags: c#, performance

I'm using a C# .NET 4.0 application on Windows 8.1 x64 that takes a long time (18 seconds) to perform certain operations. I'd like to try to diagnose why that's happening. A Process Monitor trace shows:

```
╔═══════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Relative Time ║               Operation                ║
╠═══════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 00:02.000000  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:02.000100  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:04.000000  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:04.000100  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:04.000200  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:04.000300  ║ Thread Exit                            ║
║ 00:04.000400  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:04.000500  ║ TCP Disconnect                         ║
║ 00:04.000600  ║ Thread Exit                            ║
║ 00:06.000000  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:06.000100  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:06.000200  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:06.000300  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:06.000400  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:07.000000  ║ Thread Exit                            ║
║ 00:10.000000  ║ Thread Create                          ║
║ 00:11.500000  ║ CreateFile                             ║
║               ║ // read the file contents              ║
║ 00:11.540000  ║ CloseFile                              ║
║ 00:11.541000  ║ CreateFile                             ║
║               ║ // read the file contents              ║
║ 00:11.600000  ║ CloseFile                              ║
║ 00:12.100000  ║ Thread Exit                            ║
║ 00:19.000000  ║ Thread Exit                            ║
║ 00:20.000000  ║ Thread Exit                            ║
║               ║ // from here on things respond quickly ║
╚═══════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

There are several large gaps where I would like to better understand what the program is doing. Assuming I can get the symbols (*but likely not the source*), Is there anything I can do to better understand what's going on? I'm open to using WinDbg or Windows Performance Monitor. I'd just like to get some direction in where to start with those tools to narrow in on those particular gaps.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 has some awesome performance tools throughout your application life cycle.  It also as you debug will tell you what from line to line were the speed to perform desired task.  Right now the CTP is a free download.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A much better option would be to simply run your program through a profiler. Visual Studio has a good one, its under the "Analyze" menu (at least in VS 2012).

Using a profiler will show you exactly what code is taking up all your time, down to individual method calls. With the information/tools you have, getting this information will be very difficult.

Comment: In addition, MiniProfiler by the Stack Exchange guys is a fantastic tool.

Comment: OP wrote: _Assuming I can get the symbols (but likely not the source)_. Will the Analyzer still help?

Comment: @TaW I haven't run it that way, but you *can* attach the profiler to a running instance, and if there was a pdb file there, it would presumably give you useful data.

Comment: @PaulH Misleading, no. Maybe you are doing more rendering than you think! Basically, while the profiler is always accurate to my knowledge, analyzing its results takes time and some practice.

Comment: Okay. I must have done something wrong the first time. I re-ran it and it appears the application is spending 67.3% of its time in System.Xml.GetSerializer(). I find it easy to believe it's using an XML based protocol for communications. So this is reasonable. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem! Potential solution: Make your XML smaller :)